# I need to modify a Sobel kernel for diagonal edge detection. OpenCV and C++

Tags: c++, opencv, edge-detection

I need to apply these two kernels on an image.

+1 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 -1

and
0 0 +1
0 0 0
-1 0 0

And then combine the two output images. But I have no idea how to write the loops/ apply filters to an image in general.

Comment: Please format your question correctly so it is obvious what those kernels are (presumably 3x3). They are nothing like Sobel kernels (more like roberts cross, except for being 3x4 instead of 2x2), so you probably should change your title. Have you tried just using `cv::sobel()` to see if you can detect your edges?

Answer (score 6):

You can use function called [filter2d](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#filter2d). It allows you to apply arbitrary kernel to image, so you don't need to perform any loops yourself. Just store the kernel you mentioned in Mat and provide it as input to filter2d together with your image.

Example of use:

```
float m[9] = {0,0,0,-1,0,1,0,0,0};
Mat kernel(Size(3,3), CV_32F, m);
filter2D(src, dst, -1, kernel);
```